# How to override the behavior of back button in toolbar when using navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have three fragments A,B and C , I can navigate from A to B and also from A to C. when I navigate from A to B using navigation component I see a back arrow in the AppBar which navigates back to A. I want to show a dialog like Image below when that arrow is pressed. but I don't want to see that dialog when I navigate back from C to A. is there any way to have this behavior in only one fragment? I tried to use requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback but it only works for back button. Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the activity, you can intercept navigate up to check if there's any `onBackPressedDispatcher` currently set and in that case delegate the navigate up action to the fragment:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks()) {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        true
    } else {
        navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Then from the fragment, you can use the `onBackPressedDispatcher` as you did:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) { showMyExitDialog() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, by overriding `onOptionsItemSelected()` & `onBackPressed()` methods, it will handle both scenarios, your toolbar back button and hardware back button

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // PUT YOUR Custom implementation here, related to showing dialog


}
```

Comment: I tried still nothing,  that arrow is added automatically,I guess it's part of the NavigationUI

Comment: did you try ovverriding onOptionsItemSelected() method, just copy my full code, it should work

Comment: yes I did, I don't think it works for navigation component

Comment: you can remove navigation bar in your theme and can add toolbar instead

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not really clear.. but have you tried overidding the onback button pressed method to show your dialog..
But if u can u should edit your question to fully explain what you want